# InputDialog/MessageDialog with a textbox in C# XAML Windows store app

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8, popup, messagedialog

I'm trying to create a MessageDialog with a TextBox that allows user to enter a word I didn't find how do I have to do.Can someone help me?

PS: I red that Callisto can do it but I didn't find how.

Thanks..

Answer (score 0):

You're correct that [Callisto](https://github.com/timheuer/callisto) does have a control **CustomDialog** that is pretty much exactly what you need.

There's an example app with Callisto, but the xaml you're looking for is in [MainPage.xaml](https://github.com/timheuer/callisto/blob/master/src/Callisto.TestApp/MainPage.xaml).